# Execute Sybase SQL Stored Procedure With Return In VB

Tags: sql, vb.net, stored-procedures, sybase

I'm trying to integrate with an application using Sybase as its backend. The application has a stored procedure for return the next primary key:

```
declare @key int
execute @key = GetNextPrimary('quotehdr')
select @key
```

If i execute the above from SQL Interactive @key comes back with the value. Now i need to execute the stored procedure and get the returned value from VB. Initially I thought there must be a way of executing the stored procedure by reformatting the SQL command into a single line statement however after reading other posts it's clear that I'll need to use the CommandType.StoredProcedure method however I'm struggling with the syntax for the parameters and getting the response:

```
    Try
        conn.Open()
        cmd.Connection = conn
        cmd.CommandText = "GetNextPrimary"
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@key", "quotehdr")
        Dim lrd As Odbc.OdbcDataReader = cmd.ExecuteReader()
        While lrd.Read()
            QuoteHdrRef = Convert.ToString(lrd(0))
        End While
    Catch ex As Exception
        'MessageBox.Show("Failed to connect to data source")
    Finally
        conn.Close()
    End Try
```

Can anyone give me and pointers

Thanks in advance
Vince

Comment: Did you get an error when you call the SP on ExecuteReader line?

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to pass any parameter if the stored procedure has the text written in your question.
The `@Key` is an internal declaration of a variable, it is not a parameter.
It is returned by the DataReader as a table of a single row with a single column.
Just remove the line that adds the parameter and you are fine.

And don't swallow the exceptions in that way. If you don't plan to do something with the exception, then remove the Catch or (for debugging purpose) just show the ex.Message property

Comment: Steve, thanks for your comments. The SQL commands at the top:

Comment: Steve, thanks for your comments. The SQL commands at the top is just an example of what I'm running in an SQL query window to execute the GetNextPrimary stored procedure. Where quotehdr is the parameter for the stored procedure. 
Here's my code now:
    cmd = New Odbc.OdbcCommand("{ CALL GetNextPrimary (?) }", conn)
    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure
    Dim param As Odbc.OdbcParameter = cmd.Parameters.Add("@tablename", Odbc.OdbcType.VarChar)
    param.Value = "quotehdr"
    Dim QuoteHdrRef As Integer = cmd.ExecuteScalar()
My problem now is Scalar just gives me 0 and nonquery -1

Comment: Can you add the code for GetNextPrimary stored procedure? I have some doubts on how you use that parameter.

Comment: The preconfigured SP that ProspectSoft installed is too long to fit in here so here's the top and bottom:
    ALTER FUNCTION "DBA"."GetNextPrimary"(in ls_Tablename varchar(128)) 
    returns integer
    NOT DETERMINISTIC 
    begin 

some other code...

    -- message ll_uniquekey type info to console;   
    if ll_uniquekey = 0 then 
      leave incrementloop 
    end if 
    end loop incrementloop; 
    return(ll_Primary) 
    end

Answer (score 0):

Turns out GetNextPrimary was a function. So used a procedure (getnextprimaryproc) to call the function:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE "DBA"."getnextprimaryproc"(in tablename varchar(128),out ll_primary integer)
begin
ll_primary=call "dba".getnextprimary(tablename)
end
```

Then used the following in VB to call

```
cmd.Connection = conn
cmd = New Odbc.OdbcCommand("{ call getnextprimaryproc (?, ?)}", conn)
Dim param As Odbc.OdbcParameter = cmd.Parameters.Add("@tablename", Odbc.OdbcType.VarChar)
param.Value = "quotehdr"
param = cmd.Parameters.Add("@ll_primary", Odbc.OdbcType.Int)
param.Direction = ParameterDirection.Output
conn.Open()
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
QuoteHdrRef = cmd.Parameters(1).Value
```